# How to loop a list while using Multi-threading in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops

I have a List to loop while using multi-thread,I will get the first item of the List and do some processing,then remove the item.
While the count of List is not greater than 0 ,fetch data from data.

In a word:
In have a lot of records in my database.I need to publish them to my server.In the process of publishing, multithreading is required and the number of threads may be 10 or less.

For example:

```
private List<string> list;

void LoadDataFromDatabase(){
  list=...;//load data from database...
}

void DoMethod()
{
  While(list.Count>0)
  {
    var item=list.FirstOrDefault();
    list.RemoveAt(0);
    DoProcess();//how to use multi-thread (custom the count of theads)?
    if(list.Count<=0)
    {
     LoadDataFromDatabase();
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me,I'm a beginner of c#,I have searched a lot of solutions, but no similar.

And more,I need to custom the count of theads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should your processing of the list be sequential? In other words, *cannot* you process element `n + 1` while not finished yet processing of element `n`? If this is your case, then **Multi-Threading** is not the right solution.

Otherwise, if your processing elements are **fully independent**, you can use `m` threads, deviding `Elements.Count / m` elements for each thread to work on

**Example**: printing a list:

```
List<int> a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4,5 , 6, 7, 8, 9 , 10 };
int num_threads = 2;
int thread_elements = a.Count / num_threads;

// start the threads
Thread[] threads = new Thread[num_threads];
for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
{
  threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Work));
  threads[i].Start(i);
}
// this works fine if the total number of elements is divisable by num_threads
// but if we have 500 elements, 7 threads, then thread_elements = 500 / 7 = 71
// but 71 * 7 = 497, so that there are 3 elements not processed
// process them here:
int actual = thread_elements * num_threads;
for (int i = actual; i < a.Count; ++i)
   Console.WriteLine(a[i]);

// wait all threads to finish
for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i)
{
  threads[i].Join();
}

void Work(object arg)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + arg + " has begun...");

  // calculate my working range [start, end)
  int id = (int)arg;
  int mystart = id * thread_elements;
  int myend = (id + 1) * thread_elements;

  // start work on my range !!
  for (int i = mystart; i < myend; ++i)
      Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + arg + " Element " + a[i]);
}
```

**ADD** For your case, (uploading to server), it is the same as the code obove. You assign a number of threads, assigning each thread number of elements (which is auto calculated in the variable `thread_elements`, so you need only to change `num_threads`). For method `Work`, all you need is replacing the line `Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + arg + " Element " + a[i]);` with you uploading code.

One more thing to keep in mind, that multi-threading is dependent on your machine CPU. If your CPU has 4 cores, for example, then the best performance obtained would be 4 threads at maximum, so that assigning each core a thread. Otherwise, if you have 10 threads, for example, they would be slower than 4 threads because they will compete on CPU cores (Unless the threads are idle, waiting for some event to occur (e.g. uploading). In this case, 10 threads can run, because they don't take %100 of CPU usage)

**WARNING:** DO NOT modify the list while any thread is working (add, remove, set element...), neither assigning two threads the same element. Such things cause you a lot of bugs and exceptions !!!

Comment: Hi Desolator,
The processing elements are independent.My problem is:I have a lot of records in my database.I need to publish them to my server.In the process of publishing, multithreading is required and the number of threads may be 10 or less.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "publishing".. Do you mean uploading or inserting to a databse ?

Comment: Yes,It means uploading

Comment: If the answer is appreciated for you, then select it as the best answer (and an up-vote will be welcome too *_^)

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple scenario that can be expanded in multiple ways if you add some details to your requirements:

```
IEnumerable<Data> LoadDataFromDatabase()
{ 
    return ...
}

void ProcessInParallel()
{
   while(true)
   {
      var data = LoadDataFromDatabase().ToList();

      if(!data.Any()) break;

      data.AsParallel().ForEach(ProcessSingleData);
   }
}

void ProcessSingleData(Data d)
{
  // do something with data
}
```

Comment: Thank you nvoigt,
Your opinion is good,but the count of list is huge,I need to specify the number of threads in while loop. Not all list item do loop one time.Because the ProcessSingleData() method will take some time.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to approach this.  You can create threads and partition the list yourself or you can take advantage of the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and utilize [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  In the example on the link you see a Action is called for each member of the list being iterated over.  If this is your first taste of threading I would also attempt to do it the old fashioned way.

Answer (score 1):

Here my opinion ;)

You can avoid use multithread if youur "List" is not really huge.

Instead of a List, you can use a Queue (FIFO - First In First Out). Then only use Dequeue() method to get one element of the Queue, DoSomeWork and get the another. Something like:

```
while(queue.Count > 0)
{
    var temp = DoSomeWork(queue.Dequeue());
}
```

I think that this will be better for your propose.

Answer (score 0):

> I will get the first item of the List and do some processing,then remove the item.

Bad.

First, you want a queue, not a list.

Second, you do not process then remove, you remove THEN process.

Why?

So that you keep the locks small. Lock list access (note you need to synchonize access), remove, THEN unlock immediately and then process. THis way you keep the locks short. If you take, process, then remove - you basically are single threaded as you have to keep the lock in place while processing, so the next thread does not take the same item again.

And as you need to synchronize access and want multiple threads this is about the only way.

Read up on the lock statement for a start (you can later move to something like spinlock). Do NOT use threads unless you ahve to put schedule Tasks (using the Tasks interface new in 4.0), which gives you more flexibility.

Comment: Or use a ConcurrentQueue<T> and avoid the need for locks

Comment: @leon Actually this does not avoid the needs for locking - it just moves them INTO the queue. Now, given that this is a beginner trying to learn, I would say this is counter productive. A proper learning experience does not start by taking a block that is prepared and not understanding it.